# Gradle Build Variant window in Android Studio 3.4

Tags: android-studio

I have updated Andorid Studio yesterday. Now I am unable to see the tab for changing gradle build variant. Is that option replaced somewhere?

[image: sc]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes it gets hidden under the slider. You can make it visible at clicking on window (see below image, "window" option marked with arrow)

[image]

---

Another option is, you can go to this option via `View -> Tool Window -> Build Variants`.

Refer image below

[image]

Comment: Actually, this answer was not solution for me. What happened is - I tried hiding one of the available tool window then I realised that it was below them, and because I could not scroll them so it was not getting visible. But this answer can help someone.

Comment: @Khemraj Answer updated. And please feel free to add your inputs to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, build Variant is available in 3.4, might be it is hide from your studio, you can see it from

`View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variant`

Answer (score 0):

No option are not replaced in 3.4 android studio. If you have removed by mistakenly you can always add from View -> Tool Windows -> Build Variant. You can even drag and drop Build Variant from left toolbar to any specific location in android studio. [image: Build Variant in android studio]